# Going back to the previous Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-listfragment, back-stack

I have a program where when one user clicks on a button, it takes them from one fragment to another. The issues is that I want the previous fragment to reappear once the click the back button. Code below:

This is creating the first fragment:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.team_fragment_holder, teamFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

And this is switching to the second fragment:

```
setContentView(R.layout.mixed_team_holder);
    FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();
    fragTrans.add(R.id.team_1,team1);
    fragTrans.add(R.id.team_2, team2);
    fragTrans.commit();
```

The problem right now is that when i hit the back button, a blank page appears (i assume is the (R.id.team_fragment_holder). Any idea to make the first fragment reappear along with all the information on it?

Note: all fragments extends listfragment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Your initial fragment transaction should not be added to the backstack and the second one should.  The blank page you see when pressing back is the result of removing the `teamFragment` because it is on the backstack.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.team_fragment_holder, teamFragment).commit();
```

and

```
FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();
fragTrans.add(R.id.team_1,team1);
fragTrans.add(R.id.team_2, team2);
fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
fragTrans.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks of the response but it didn't work. After i click the back button, I still get a blank page. Do I have to save everything from the previous fragment before i create the next one and reload it back in after the back button is pressed?

Comment: Or maybe the blank screen resulted because I set a new layout to display the team1 and team2 fragments?

Comment: It's probably because you set a new layout.  You shouldn't have to re-set your layout like that.  It can/should all be handled with Fragments programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You need add the fragment to Back Stack.

```
FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();
fragTrans.add(R.id.team_1,team1);
fragTrans.add(R.id.team_2, team2);
fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);//Here add the fragment
fragTrans.commit();
```

And you need validate the back button.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
     } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
     }
}
```

Comment: `Activity` already handles popping the fragment backstack for you.  There's no need to override onBackPressed().

Comment: Same Problem as the first answer: a blank page is displayed after i press the back button. Just wondering if i need to save everything on the first fragment before calling the second one and reload it afterwards. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.fragment_button_project_location_ok:

        //getActivity().finish();
        //add back to previous screen
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```